# LocalDB and SqlException

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have literally just created an ASP.NET MVC template project and trying to register a new account and getting this error.

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +970
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +802

In the server object browser, I cannot even expand the SQL Server.

This is the connection string in `web.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-VisitorPortal-20160628102215.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-VisitorPortal-20160628102215;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I can't believe how hard it is to get just the basic template project up and running. Seems like black magic working with VS. I am using VS 2015 professional.

Comment: In the server object explorer I cannot see my localdb either.

Comment: Ok there is no files in App_Data, so maybe the local db file is not created? How do I fix this?

Comment: Change your connection string to this : `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DB_Name;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Comment: connectionString="Server=WUJH;Database=TEST_400;Trusted_Connection=yes providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"". Do you have at least an SQL server installed?

Comment: I get the same error for both connection strings above.

Comment: I've tried another project that used to work in another PC but get the same error in this PC. I think its something to do with my VS environment. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a SQL server installed?

Comment: No I don't think I do. Installing SQL 2014 express now. I'm a bit confused how the localDB works. So it still needs SQL server installed?

Comment: Yes . I suggest you read [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string) to get a better understanding.

Comment: Yes. I see your error has "SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed.." Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, this is not like working with SQLite - although it's just a file, you still need SQL Server Express installed; from then on, setting the connection string should be straightforward ("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\[...]")

Comment: Thanks guys that was the issue, I installed SQL express and all is good. I've also decided to stop using localdb and use SQLexpress instead as from reading the documentation above localdb is not recommended sounds like it is more for development.